# Including social icons at the bottom-right corner using bootstrap grid system

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add three social icons (with inline display) at the bottom right corner of my landing page using the bootstrap grid system. I am not using bootstrap font-awesome. I have tried doing the following but the icons are not displaying inline, but displaying downwards.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">

        // this was for the stuff placed on the bottom left.

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xlg-6">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xlg-4">
                    <ul class="contact list-style">
                        <li class="uppercase blue-text-color">Company</li>
                        <li class="active uppercase"> <a href="">About</a> </li>
                        <li class="uppercase"> <a href="">Careers</a> </li>
                        <li class="uppercase"> <a href="">Blogs</a> </li>
                    </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xlg-4">
                <ul class="contact list-style">
                    <li class="uppercase blue-text-color">Get in touch</li>
                    <li class="active uppercase"> <a href="">contact us</a> </li>
                    <li>1-800-706-0806</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xlg-4">
                <ul class="contact list-style">
                    <li class="uppercase blue-text-color">help</li>
                    <li class="active uppercase"> <a href="">Privacy policy</a> </li>
                    <li class="uppercase"> <a href="">terms of service</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div> 

         // now the following is for the icons i wish to include
        // in the bottom right.

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xlg-6">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xlg-2">
                    <ul class="list-style" style="display: inline;">
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="./img/new/facebook.png" alt="facebook" width="50px" height="50px"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="./img/new/twitter.png" alt="twitter" width="50px" height="50px"></a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="./img/new/linkedin.png" alt="linkedin" width="50px" height="50px"></a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

CSS (all that has been used in this code other than the linked bootstrap.min.css):

```
.content {
 padding: 30px 10px;
}

.contact a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #888888;
 }

.list-style {
 list-style: none;
 }

.uppercase {
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.blue-text-color {
 color: #33BBDB;
 }
```

right now I have this:

[image]

but I want something like this:

[image]

I am very new to bootstrap and I am sure I am missing somewhere. I have been trying to solve this since long but haven't been able to find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.list-style li{ display:inline;}`

and remove the `ul` above div `col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xlg-2`

Comment: this didn't work. I have already included the inline style as an attribute in `<ul>`. I think I am making a mistake with the grid system somewhere.

Comment: remove the `ul` above div `col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xlg-2` because of that size adjusted.

Answer (score 1):

Pleasee do remove the `<div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xlg-2">` above `ul` and also include container

Please have rewritten code as:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">   
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xlg-6">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xlg-4">
                <ul class="contact list-style">
                    <li class="uppercase blue-text-color">Company</li>
                    <li class="active uppercase"> <a href="">About</a> </li>
                    <li class="uppercase"> <a href="">Careers</a> </li>
                    <li class="uppercase"> <a href="">Blogs</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xlg-4">
                <ul class="contact list-style">
                    <li class="uppercase blue-text-color">Get in touch</li>
                    <li class="active uppercase"> <a href="">contact us</a> </li>
                    <li>1-800-706-0806</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xlg-4">
                <ul class="contact list-style">
                    <li class="uppercase blue-text-color">help</li>
                    <li class="active uppercase"> <a href="">Privacy policy</a> </li>
                    <li class="uppercase"> <a href="">terms of service</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xlg-6">
            <ul class="list-style" style="display: inline;">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="./img/new/facebook.png" alt="facebook" width="50px" height="50px"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="./img/new/twitter.png" alt="twitter" width="50px" height="50px"></a></li> 
                <li><a href="#"><img src="./img/new/linkedin.png" alt="linkedin" width="50px" height="50px"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Also add style

```
    ul.list-style li {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use

```
li {display : inline; }
```

But this will change all your list items to inline position thus use

```
.list_style li { display: inline;}
```

Which will only access the list inside the list_style class

Comment: This is the same what Mani answered. But thanks anyway. :)